# Concurrency issues with crawler

Tags: go

I try to build concurrent crawler based on Tour and some others SO answers regarding that. What I have currently is below but I think I have here two subtle issues.

1. Sometimes I get 16 urls in response and sometimes 17 (debug print in `main`). I know it because when I even change `WriteToSlice` to `Read` then in `Read` sometimes 'Read: end, counter = ' is never reached and it's always when I get 16 urls.
2. I have troubles with `err` channel, I get no messages in this channel, even when I run my main `Crawl` method with address like [www.golang.org](http://www.golang.org) so without valid schema error should be send via `err` channel

Concurrency is really difficult topic, help and advice will be appreciated

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

type urlCache struct {
    urls map[string]struct{}
    sync.Mutex
}

func (v *urlCache) Set(url string) bool {
    v.Lock()
    defer v.Unlock()

    _, exist := v.urls[url]
    v.urls[url] = struct{}{}

    return !exist
}

func newURLCache() *urlCache {
    return &urlCache{
        urls: make(map[string]struct{}),
    }
}

type results struct {
    data chan string
    err  chan error
}

func newResults() *results {
    return &results{
        data: make(chan string, 1),
        err:  make(chan error, 1),
    }
}

func (r *results) close() {
    close(r.data)
    close(r.err)
}

func (r *results) WriteToSlice(s *[]string) {
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-r.data:
            *s = append(*s, data)
        case err := <-r.err:
            fmt.Println("e ", err)
        }
    }
}

func (r *results) Read() {
    fmt.Println("Read: start")
    counter := 0
    for c := range r.data {
        fmt.Println(c)
        counter++
    }
    fmt.Println("Read: end, counter = ", counter)
}

func crawl(url string, depth int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, cache *urlCache, res *results) {
    defer wg.Done()

    if depth == 0 || !cache.Set(url) {
        return
    }

    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        res.err <- err
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    node, err := html.Parse(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        res.err <- err
        return
    }

    urls := grablUrls(response, node)

    res.data <- url

    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go crawl(url, depth-1, wg, cache, res)
    }
}

func grablUrls(resp *http.Response, node *html.Node) []string {
    var f func(*html.Node) []string
    var results []string

    f = func(n *html.Node) []string {
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
            for _, a := range n.Attr {
                if a.Key != "href" {
                    continue
                }
                link, err := resp.Request.URL.Parse(a.Val)
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
                results = append(results, link.String())
            }
        }

        for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            f(c)
        }

        return results
    }

    res := f(node)
    return res
}

// Crawl ...
func Crawl(url string, depth int) []string {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    output := &[]string{}
    visited := newURLCache()
    results := newResults()
    defer results.close()

    wg.Add(1)
    go crawl(url, depth, wg, visited, results)
    go results.WriteToSlice(output)
    // go results.Read()
    wg.Wait()

    return *output
}

func main() {
    r := Crawl("https://www.golang.org", 2)
    // r := Crawl("www.golang.org", 2) // no schema, error should be generated and send via err

    fmt.Println(len(r))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your questions 1 and 2 are a result of the same bug.

In `Crawl()` you are not waiting for this go routine to finish: `go results.WriteToSlice(output)`. On the last `crawl()` function, the wait group is released, the output is returned and printed before the `WriteToSlice` function finishes with the `data` and `err` channel. So what has happened is this:

1. `crawl()` finishes, placing data in `results.data` and `results.err`.
2. Waitgroup `wait()` unblocks, causing `main()` to print the length of the result `[]string`
3. `WriteToSlice` adds the last data (or err) item to the channel

You need to return from `Crawl()` not only when the data is done being written to the channel, but also when the channel is done being read in it's entirety (including the buffer). A good way to do this is close channels when you are sure that you are done with them. By organizing your code this way, you can block on the go routine that is draining the channels, and instead of using the wait group to release to main, you wait until the channels are 100% done.

You can see this gobyexample https://gobyexample.com/closing-channels. Remember that when you close a channel, the channel can still be used until the last item is taken. So you can close a buffered channel, and the reader will still get all the items that were queued in the channel.

There is some code structure that can change to make this cleaner, but here is a quick way to fix your program. Change `Crawl` to block on `WriteToSlice`. Close the data channel when the crawl function finishes, and wait for `WriteToSlice` to finish.

```golang
// Crawl ...
func Crawl(url string, depth int) []string {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    output := &[]string{}
    visited := newURLCache()
    results := newResults()

    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go crawl(url, depth, wg, visited, results)
        wg.Wait()
        // All data is written, this makes `WriteToSlice()` unblock
        close(results.data)
    }()

    // This will block until results.data is closed
    results.WriteToSlice(output)
    close(results.err)

    return *output
}
```

Then on write to slice, you have to check for the closed channel to exit the for loop:

```golang
func (r *results) WriteToSlice(s *[]string) {
    for {
        select {
        case data, open := <-r.data:
            if !open {
                return // All data done
            }
            *s = append(*s, data)
        case err := <-r.err:
            fmt.Println("e ", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full code: https://play.golang.org/p/GBpGk-lzrhd (it won't work in the playground)

Comment: It works perfectly, great answer and explanation. Thanks!